# SharePoint Server with Infopath, submit a form without knowing that your saving it

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services, form

We are looking into using InfoPath with our current SharePoint infrastructure to submit easy non workflow forms that we currently are creating in asp and I have some basic questions I hope that you can help me with.

1. Is it possible to embed a from to any SharePoint page using a webpart?
2. Is it possible to only give write (remove the view/edit) permission on the lists they are submitting the form to?
3. Is it possible to hide the controls on top of the form which has the save, save as buttons and instead add a submit button. So that the users thinks that they are submitting a form instead of saving it? (auto generate a filename when clicking submit and then redirect them to the previous page)

Answer (score 2):

Here are answers:

1. Yes. Take a look at [InfoPath 2010 Introduction Part 3: SharePoint Form Web Part](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jessmeats/archive/2010/01/20/infopath-2010-introduction-part-3-sharepoint-form-web-part.aspx)
2. No. It is not logical. Maybe you can just hide your list from users (navigation) as simplest woraround.
3. Yes. Take a look at [InfoPath 2010 – turn off Ribbon](http://allthingsdotnet.net/?p=685) and then you need to add Submit connection and button for submit action.

Answer (score 1):

To further expand on Vedran's point 2, you can create custom permissions for the list to only allow Add items, but this will automatically include view permissions as well.  You could create a default view that shows no items or have a filtered view to show only the items submitted by the current user (Created By equals [Me]).

Comment: +1 nice expansion

Comment: Alternatively, use two libraries, one where the forms get saved to, and another where the forms will actually live, and write an event receiver that will run elevated and shuffle everything over. This way, users will never be able to edit their submissions.